# Logging Firebase queries in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Cloud-Firestore database in my application. 
Is it possible to logging Firebase queries in Flutter?
At the moment, my application generates a huge number of write requests in Firestore. How to detect which queries are performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in to the Firestore Flutter SDK to enable/control logging. If you need more information than it logs by default, you'll have to find all the Firestore statements in your code and add logging yourself.

If you're willing to go into the native Android or iOS app, you can enable logging there ( [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#setLoggingEnabled(boolean)), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Firestore#enablelogging_:) ) there to see additional information about what is being sent/received.

To get an overview on what operations all clients are doing, you can [monitor the Firestore usage in Cloud Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage) (which was called StackDriver until recently).

Comment: Thank you! Really helpfull!